# Mass wave of reopen votes - coincidence or something happens?

Tags: support, voting-to-reopen

I just voted on 17 reopen votes. None of the questions was recently edited. I never seen any queue that big here, so I just wonder, is it something that happens from time to time? Or maybe something wrong is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of a change to how questions are automatically added to the reopen queue, rolled out a few days ago.

See [Lots of questions in the reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue) for the full details